# How to get local date & time of browser in the file when the file itself in rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to the browser/local date and time in a file[PDF] . My issue is that the rendering of the file/PDF happens on the server itself. So there's no way I can think of in which I can use a JavaScript, since my rendering is happening on the server side.
Any suggestions on how can I pass my current browser time directly in that file or anyother suggestions which can help?

Template: `<p>Generated {{today|date:'short'}}</p>`

TypeScript: `today: number = new Date();`

Comment: you _can_ run js in pdfs, but it's uncommon.

Comment: so pass the date in the request and use it when you are generating it?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your date from the client to the server via http and print that date on the pdf, then send the pdf to the client.